# Solr search response Order : token position based

Tags: search, solr, autocomplete, lucene, term-suggester

I want search results document in sorted order of matched token position

example:  I have following docs:

```
     1. indian institute of technology
     2. cultural arts institute
     3. institute of Management
     4. institute of Arts


search query : ins*
localhost:6983/solr/ts/select?fl=name&indent=true&q.op=OR&q=name%3Ains*

Expected response :
```

```
     3. institute of Management  ----> (institute position ->1)
     4. institute of Arts        -----> (institute position ->1)
     1. indian institute of technology --> (institute position ->2)
     2. cultural arts institute   ------> (institute position ->3)
```

file : managed-schema

```
  <fieldType name="single_keyword" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.ClassicTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.ClassicTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

```
Debug reference : 
http://localhost:6983/solr/ts/select?fl=name&indent=true&q.op=OR&q=name%3Ains*&debug=true

"debug": {
"rawquerystring": "name:ins*",
"querystring": "name:ins*",
"parsedquery": "name:ins*",
"parsedquery_toString": "name:ins*",
"explain": {
"institute_187": "\n1.0 = name:ins*\n",
"institute_188": "\n1.0 = name:ins*\n",
"institute_189": "\n1.0 = name:ins*\n",
"institute_1036": "\n1.0 = name:ins*\n",
"institute_1037": "\n1.0 = name:ins*\n",
"institute_2027": "\n1.0 = name:ins*\n",
"institute_2028": "\n1.0 = name:ins*\n",
"institute_2029": "\n1.0 = name:ins*\n"
},
"QParser": "LuceneQParser",
"timing": {......}}}
```

I Have tried this with autoSugest but it doesn't serve my use case, drawback of using autosuggest: unable to run filter on multiple value and field, unable to return multiple fields in response

Answer (score 0):

There may be an easier way to accomplish what you want, but this could definitely be handled using a a custom scorer.  [This blog](https://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2014/03/12/using-customscorequery-for-custom-solrlucene-scoring/) explains the process of creating a custom scorer and outlines other angles through which you may be able to tackle this issue